# Why doesn't this C++ code work?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, unhandled-exception

```
int Socket::Connect(const std::string& host, int port)
{

    if(this->_connected)
        throw "Socket is already connected";
    // Get the IP from the string


    hostent* ip = gethostbyname(host.c_str());

    /*if(server == NULL)
        throw strerror(WSAGetLastError());*/

    // Information for WinSock.
    sockaddr_in addr;
    // Clear up the memory
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr = *((in_addr *)ip->h_addr); 

    // Try and connect
   if(WSAConnect(this->_socket, (sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) != 0)
        throw strerror(WSAGetLastError()); // this is being thrown but not caught?
   this->_connected = true;
    return 0;
}
```

The error is

"Unknown Error"

and here is the main function

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    try{


    Socket* socket = new Socket();
    if(socket->Connect("google.com", 80) == 0)
        std::cout << "[-] connected..." << endl;

    std::string line = socket->RecvLine();
    std::cout << line << endl;
    }
    catch(char* errcstr)
    {
        std::cout << errcstr << endl;
    }
    catch(int err)
    {
        std::cout << err << endl;
    }
    catch(std::string errstr)
    {
        std::cout << errstr << endl;
    }
    catch(exception ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

So it should catch any exceptions as far as I know. How can I fix this? (There shouldn't an exception at all since it's connected to google.com and winsock is initialized etc)

UPDATE: The error is actually being thrown after WSAConnect but there shouldn't be a problem connecting and none of my catch statements are being used for some reason.

UPDATE 2: Well now it catches the error but it says "Unknown Error" which is useless to me. Why won't it connect to google?

SOLVED: thanks!

Comment: `gethostbyname` is a C API and will never throw a C++ exception. Are you sure that's where the error is emanating from?

Comment: Enable first-chance exception handling (in Visual Studio, Ctrl+Alt+E and check all the checkboxes) and run attached to the debugger.  This will allow you to break when the exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks James. The exception is right after WSAConnect (so it's failing to connect and none of my catch statements are working for some reason)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strerror() returns a char* on windows so you need a catch(char* error)

Answer (score 2):

strerror() is not appropriate here.  It looks like you're trying to move Unix code to Windows; strerror() is the right thing on Unix.  connect() on Unix stores error codes in the global `errno` value, and strerror() translates `errno` codes to error strings.  Winsock handles error codes entirely differently, even down to the actual error values, so that they're not compatible with strerror().

See [item 2.8](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/newbie.html#errmsg) in the Winsock Programmer's FAQ for the correct way to turn Winsock error numbers into error message strings.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I meant to post this as an answer not a comment.

You're throwing a `char*` but there is no catch clause to catch it. Perhaps this is what you wanted to do:

```
if(WSAConnect(this->_socket, (sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) != 0)
        throw std::runtime_error(strerror(WSAGetLastError()));
```

UPDATE:

Is there any particular reason why you're using WSAConnect() instead of connect()? This should work:

```
_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
if ( connect( _socket, &addr, sizeof addr ) == SOCKET_ERROR ) {
    //Error
}
```

You might also find this useful: http://www.madwizard.org/programming/tutorials/netcpp